# What are the $GL_n(F)$-orbits of a group action on the set of idempotent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S= \{A \in M_{n \times n}(F):A^2=A\}$ (set of idempotent matrices). The general linear group $G=GL_n(F)$ acts on $S$ by $A.g=gAg^{-1}$ (conjugation).

I'm having trouble visualizing the $GL_n(F)$-orbits of $S$. What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: idempotent matrices are diagonalizable. What do the diagonal conjugates look like?

Comment: This is a good hint, thank you. Please let me think about this with your hint in mind..

Comment: @user13451345 no problem.